# Slack API: Get channel managers of a channel

Tags: slack, slack-api

In the Slack GUI, when listing users of a channel, you are able to see who in the channel is a channel manager.

I am trying to get this same information from the API, but when using the [conversations.members](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.members) method, I only get a flat list of users with no information on who the channel manager(s) are. Is there another method for getting the channel managers?

Answer (score 1):

Try [this API](https://api.slack.com/methods/admin.roles.listAssignments). The `role_id` `Rl0A` is for channel manager.